# Can I read all versions of one cell in cassandra?

Tags: java, scala, cassandra

I want to retrieve all versions of one cell. However, it seems Cassandra API can only get latest version / timestamp. For example using hector:

```
import me.prettyprint.hector.api._
import me.prettyprint.hector.api.factory._
import me.prettyprint.cassandra.serializers._
import me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.template._
object GetExample extends App {
    val cluster = HFactory.getOrCreateCluster("test_cluster", "127.0.0.1:9160")
    val keyspace = HFactory.createKeyspace("test_keyspace", cluster)
    val colFamilyName = "test_table"

    val template = new ThriftColumnFamilyTemplate(keyspace, colFamilyName,
                                                  StringSerializer.get(),      
                                                  StringSerializer.get())
    val result = template.queryColumns("row1")
    System.out.println(result.getString("qual1"))
    System.out.println(result.getColumn("qual1").getClock())

    HFactory.shutdownCluster(cluster)
}
```

`getClock()` only gives me the latest timestamp.

One reason I want all timestamps is that in Cassandra's own API, deletion can designate a timestamp to delete values older than that. So how am I suppose to know which timestamp to use if I can't retrieve them in the first place? Besides, I may want to use timestamp to store different versions of one cell, as a quite useful modeling mechanism.

Can Cassandra do that?

I searched a little and found Jonathan Ellis once said: "No, we're not planning to add support for retrieving old versions." But it was Mar. 2010. Is it still true? If yes, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that columns have timestamps is so that Cassandra can handle conflict resolution when multiple clients write to the same column.

If you want to keep multiple versions of column you could use a composite column of **OriginalColumnName::TimeUUID**. Then you could slice out all columns by the OriginalColumnName to get the historical values of that column. Here is an example [using hector and composite columns](http://randomizedsort.blogspot.com/2011/11/cassandra-range-query-using.html).

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid as it stands, Cassandra cannot do that.

Acunu's version of Cassandra (http://www.acunu.com/acunu-data-platform/) has the ability to take snapshots and read (old) data from them.  You can even branch from a snapshot and have a complete version tree, where writes to different versions are completely isolated.

NB: I work for Acunu.

Comment: Thanks for confirming this, @tom.wilkie. And good to know there's Acunu.